# ARM Assembly, register not being set to 0?

Tags: assembly, arm, cpu, cpu-registers

```
start

read

    BL  getkey              ; read key from console
    CMP R0, #0x0D           ; while (key != CR)
    BEQ endRead             ; {
    BL  sendchar            ;   echo key back to console    

    CMP R0, #' '            ; if (ro = ' ')
    BNE nocount             ;{                          
    ADD R7, R7, #1          ; r7 += 1
    LDR R4, =0              ; r4 = 0
nocount                     ;}

    MOV R6, R0              ; Store input in R6
    SUB R6, R6, #'0'        ; Convert from decimal to hex
    MULS R4, R5, R4         ; If there is another input, multiply total by 10
    ADDS R4, R4, R6         ; Add the input to the total

    ADD R8, R4, R8          ;sum

    B   read    

endRead                 

end                     

stop    B   stop

    END
```

Hi,
I'm trying to have my code so when there is a space entered into the console, 1 will be added to R7 and R4 will be set to 0.

When a space is added, R4 is set to 0xFFFFFFF0, but when I add '5' to this, I get 0xFFFFFFF65. I expect to just get 0x00000005. This is weird, because when I put the same command outside the compare, it works. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Also I want r8 to be the sum of numbers entered, it doesn't seem to be working properly, can anyone tell me why?

Comment: I'm not, I just didn't include that part of the code.
Every time there is an input I take away '0' from it.

Comment: OK - you need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Isn't `BEQ` the wrong branch test? When `space`  is entered, it skips the 2 lines.

Comment: Yes sorry, that shouldn't be there, what I originally had was BNE

Comment: This is one reason why we need the MCVE - so that *you* can verify it too, instead of posting "something like my code".

Comment: Code has been updated.

Comment: How does `R5` magically contain 10?

Comment: I used 
LDR R5, =10

Comment: Also verify `BL sendchar` does not destroy your  registers. Learn to use a debugger.

Comment: After establishing that a `space` was entered, you however still perform the `SUB R6, R6, #'0' ; Convert from decimal to hex` code section.

Comment: BL sendchar destroys R0, R1, R2 and, R3 but I don't use any of those registers.

Comment: How could I change it so I don't execute that line if there is a space?

Comment: Er... an unconditional branch to `read`?

Comment: "but I don't use any of those registers" really? `CMP R0, #' '` does not use R0? That's news to me...

Comment: Where are `r7` and `r8` initially assigned a value?  Also, if this is ever called from a C function, you will need to preserve a bunch of registers.

Answer (score 1):

Have you explored conditional execution ADD, etc?

Assumes: ARMv7 
My machine = Linux raspberrypi 4.4.26-v7+ #915 SMP Thu Oct 20 17:08:44 BST 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux

```
        cmp r0, #0x20          // white space - space char
        addeq r7, r7, #1        // conditional add
        eoreq r4, r4            // conditional zero
```

Comment: I am not too hot on ARM, but wouldn't `addeq r7, r7, #1` affect the `Z` flag ahead of `eoreq r4, r4`?

Comment: @WeatherVane No, because it's `add`, not `adds` ;)

Comment: Oh, and there's really no need for obscure x86-isms on ARM - when all the instruction encodings are the same size, you don't save anything by not using the obvious `moveq, r4, #0`.

Comment: @Notlikethat - right. But isn't this point,in the instance case, just a matter of preference?

Answer (score 0):

```
LDR R4, =0
```

doesn't assign zero to the register. It loads the register from the memory address 0. Use

```
MOV R4, #0
```

instead.

Comment: It **does** assign zero to the register. In fact GAS even replaces it with a `mov` automatically.

Comment: @SeamusW - Can you share your scan (i.e., getkey funtion) code?

Comment: @Jester  Actually, ldr r4,=#0 is just loading a constant into the reg. If we do mov r0,#0 then try ldr r4,[r0], we'll probably get a seg fault

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the summation of the numbers; please the example below of a simple decremented loop where the sum of each number is added to R1. Hope this helps.

```
main:   nop

        eor r2, r2
        mov r1, #0xf
        1:

        add r2, r2, r1
        bl write

        subs r1, #1
        bne 1b
```

OUTPUT:

```
15 15
14 29
13 42
12 54
11 65
10 75
9 84
8 92
7 99
6 105
5 110
4 114
3 117
2 119
1 120
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone, the code is correct, it was just not in the right position, thanks everyone!

Comment: No, it's not.  You need to at least set registers to initial known values.